# Run Javascript in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to run JS in server (instead of UI). I know I can do this via shinyjs package using runjs function but I want to know how can I do this via native shiny package. I tried via `session$sendCustomMessage()` and `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler( )` but it does not work.

**My Attempt**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

jscode <- "
  window.close();
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    actionButton("close", "Close app"),
    tags$script(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('closeWindow', function(data) {
       data.message
      });"
    )
  ) 
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$close, {
    
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "closeWindow", list(message = jscode))

  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser =T)
```

**This works with shinyjs**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "
  window.close();
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("close", "Close app")
  ) 
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$close, {
    
    runjs(jscode)
    
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser =T)
```

Comment: This JS code closes the window. The window is in the UI. This JS code should run "in UI"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just passing the jscode value as a string to your javascript message handler. You can only pass strings or objects, not executable code. Therefore, in order to actually run the code, you need to `eval()` the string. This should work

```
    tags$script(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('closeWindow', function(data) {
       eval(data.message)
      });"
    )
```